# System of equations $\lfloor x\rfloor+\{y\}=1.2,\ \{x\}+\lfloor y\rfloor = 3.3$

Tags: systems-of-equations, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Solve over reals the system of equations:

$$\lfloor x\rfloor+\{y\}=1.2$$

$$\{x\}+\lfloor y\rfloor = 3.3$$

My idea: Because $0\le \{y\} < 1$ and $\lfloor x\rfloor$ is an integer, the only possibility is $\lfloor x\rfloor = 1$ and $\{y\}=0.2$.

Because $0\le \{x\} < 1$ and $\lfloor y\rfloor$ is an integer, the only possibility is $\lfloor y\rfloor = 3$ and $\{x\}=0.3$.

The solution is $x=\lfloor x\rfloor+\{x\}=1.3$ and $y=\lfloor y\rfloor+\{y\}=3.2$. Is it correct? Can I write this idea this more cleanly?

Comment: What do you mean by more cleanly? Like a more "crisp" solution? This looks like fine reasoning to me.

Comment: I mean like 'Statement A => Statement B => ... => Solution', not like 'The only possibility is...'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's right. You can make it cleaner by taking the integer and fractional parts, and using the fact these functions are idempotent (in fact, they're linear projection operators summing to the identity).

Comment: You mean like $1=\lfloor 1.2 \rfloor = \lfloor \lfloor x\rfloor + \{y \}\rfloor=\lfloor \lfloor x\rfloor \rfloor+0= \lfloor x\rfloor$ ? That looks better.

Comment: @ryan Yes, that's it.